# Access the onClick event of a specific element of a longlistselector wp8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I seem to have run into something I can't quite solve. I have a longlistselector of letters databound to an observable collection of chars. I'd like to be able to click on the first item of that longlistselector and have something happen, but I can't seem to figure out how to access its onClick event.

Here is the code for the longlistselector

```
<phone:LongListSelector x:Name="uScrambleLLS"  Margin="-12,0,0,540" ItemsSource="{Binding Scramble}" SelectionChanged="uScrambleLLS_SelectionChanged" LayoutMode="Grid" GridCellSize="50,50">
    <phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
               <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
    </phone:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: What OnClick event? Any reason the SelectionChanged event not work for you?

Comment: I was under the impression that the onclick event would handle it.

Answer (score -1):

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}" Tap="MyTextBlock_Tap" />

void MyTextBlock_Tap(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock tb = (TextBlock)sender;
    // Do stuff with the item
}
```

Comment: this answer has no relation regarding Longlistselector as you can not write tap events of every element to get selected item

Comment: Huh? You can check if it's the first item with

if (tb.DataContext == Scramble[0])

Comment: Because the longlistselector is databound, what it contains is not hard-coded. This isn't what I'm looking for at all.

Comment: Uhh... maybe you should reword your question. What are you looking for?